# Modifying Excel using xlrd and xlwt

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a new excel from an existing excel . There ares `3 Sheets` in my old excel say `first` , `second` , `third`. I am able to copy the contents of first sheet succesfully in new excel which is based on some condition i.e my code before `while index < 3 :` works perfectly fine . For sheet `second` and `third` I want to copy them as they are in `original excel sheet`. But When the copy starts for `second` sheet I get an error :-

```
sheet1 = w.add_sheet('Info')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 331, in add_sheet
raise Exception("duplicate worksheet name %r" % sheetname)
```

My code is as follows:-

```
newexcel = "newexcel.xls"
    count = 0
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('/home/sam/myexcel.xls')
    w = Workbook()
    sheet = w.add_sheet('Input_Resource')
    index = 0
    s = wb.sheet_by_index(index)
    if index < 1 :
        index =+ 1
        for row in range(s.nrows):
            coln =0
            val = s.cell(row,coln).value
            if val in MissingId :
                mylist.append(val)
                count += 1
            else:
                for col in range(s.ncols):
                    val = s.cell(row,col).value
                    sheet.write(row-count,col,val)
    while index < 3 :
        if index == 1 :
            sheet1 = w.add_sheet('Info')
        else :
            sheet2 = w.add_sheet('Sheet3')

        s = wb.sheet_by_index(index)
        index =+ 1
        for row in range(s.nrows):
            coln =0
            val = s.cell(row,coln).value
            for col in range(s.ncols):
                val = s.cell(row,col).value
                if index == 1:
                    sheet1.write(row,col,val)
                else :
                    sheet2.write(row,col,val)
w.save(newexcel)
```

Any Help or hint is appreciated :)

Comment: can you provide a link to the myexcel.xls file you using

Comment: Have a look at [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), I believe if you follow that approach you can reduce the code in your question and maybe even discover exactly what has gone wrong. It has helped me in the past.

Comment: did you solve this issue. Please update the question if you have, otherwise I'll have another go at it.

Answer (score 0):

Below some idea for check duplicate sheets:

```
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
#Adding 2 sheets
ws1 = wb.add_sheet('One')
ws2 = wb.add_sheet('Two')

sheets = wb._Workbook__worksheets #Getting sheets list
sheet_names = [] #List for shhets names
for sheet in sheets:
     sheet_names.append(
         sheet.get_name() #getting sheet name
         ) 
print sheet_names
print True if u"One" in sheet_names else False #check for our name
wb.save('test.xls')
```

Results:

```
$python simple.py 
[u'One', u'Two']
True
```